# ScrollView does not expand

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have nine ImageView(s) inside scrollview and each one has a LinearLayout below it with "gone" visibility. when one of the image clicked the linearlayout below it set to visible.
I added scrollToTop() function to scroll image view to the top to be able to see the list but the last one (image #9) does not response to scroll and stay at the bottom. the list is get visible but I have to scroll manually.

```html
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">                
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    .
                    .
                    .
                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_img1" 
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"/> 
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical" 
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:visibility="gone">
                            <TextView android:text="1" style="@style/tv_number"  />
                            <TextView android:text="1" style="@style/tv_number"  />
                            <TextView android:text="1" style="@style/tv_number"  />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

the Java Functions:

```js
 scrollToTop(containerList.getTop(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first internal `LinearLayout` should be `layout_height` `wrap_content`

Comment: no difference.. I think scrolltotop() done before Layout.setvisibility(visible)